# Cómo introducir una propiedad dentro del constructor de una clase

Tags: javascript

Intentaré explicarme lo mejor que pueda. Tengo las siguientes clases.

En este primero trozo lo que hago es instanciar la clase **App**

```js
// canva
// width of canvas = 15
// height of canvas = 10
// size squares = 50
// cantidad de jugadores = 2

let app = new App("canvas", 15, 10, 50, 2);
```

La clase **App**

```js
class App {
  constructor(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase, players) {
    this.map = new Map(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase);
  }
  /**
   * returns a random number between 0 and limit
   * @param limit
   * @returns {number}
   */

  static random(limit) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
  }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es dentro de la clase **App** instanciar otra clase llamada **Player**, no quiero hacerlo así `this.player1 = new Player()` sino generar ambas instanciaciones de manera dinámica.

Mi intensión es que desde **main.js** que es donde está `let app = new App`pueda indicar cuantos jugadores he de crear, sin tener que hacer ningún cambio en la clase **App**, dicho de otra manera, quiero evitar tener que escribir en **App**

```
this.player1 = new Player()

this.player2 = new Player()
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es introducir dentro del constructor ambos this de manera dinámica, así si que quiero generar 3 o 4 jugadores, no tengo que cambiar nada en **App** sólo indicar desde `let app  = new App()` la cantidad de jugadores que necesito.

Llevo ya dos días buscando cómo hacerlo he intentando opciones, pero nada, no consigo hacerlo. Estuve leyendo que con Objecto.defineProperty() se podía introducir una nueva propiedad dentro de un objeto, no obstante no conseguí hacerlo.

El otro inconveniente que tengo, es que mi intención es hacerlo dentro de la propia clase, sin acudir a una función externa. Lo intenté creando un método dentro de la propia clase(App), el cual llamaba desde el constructor, pero nada, no conseguí nada.

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, en este punto empiezo a pensar que no es posible.

Comment: ¿ Por algún motivo no puedes usar un *array* ? `this.players = [];`

Comment: @Trauma, lo intenté, pero luego tengo que acceder a cada nuevo objeto instanciado y tendría problemas. De todas maneras estuve probando y no conseguí hacerlo, igual le estuve haciendo mal.

Comment: No se que es lo que has intentado hacer (porque no lo muestras), pero hacer `players[variable_con_el_indice]` es lo mas simple que se me ocurre. En fin, tendrás que esperar a que alguien con mas conocimientos te eche una mano :-)

Comment: Cree un método dentro de la clase, el cual llamaba desde el constructor, pasandole un parámetro(n de jugadores) luego generaba un nombre compuesto por el número de jugador más el un string quedando player1, player2, etc luego con un push intenté meterlo al array, pero como el objetivo es instanciar la classe player, ,me daba error. 

era algo así como player1 = new Player(), pero esto creo no se puede meter dentro del array, voy a ver si puedo meter dentro de array un objeto, quizás es algo muy loco y no se puede, no obstante lo intentaré. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Este es el ejemplo de MDN:en [https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes/constructor][1]

```
class Square extends Polygon {
  constructor(length) {
    // Aquí, llama al constructor de la clase padre con sus longitudes
    // contemplando la anchura y la altura del Polígono
    super(length, length);
    // Nota: En las clases derivadas, super() se debe llamar primero
    // Se puede utilizar "this". Dejando esto causará un error de 
    //referencia.
    this.name = 'Square';
  }

  get area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }

  set area(value) {
    this.area = value;
  } 
}
```

Comment: No veo que esta respuesta tenga **absolutamente nada que ver** con la pregunta O_O

Comment: Gracias. @Salvador Gonzalés. Lo que pasa es que si utilizo extends me veo obligado a crear una clase hija de para extender la clase padre, pero no es lo que quiero, ya que tendría muchas mas líneas de código que sólo agregando directamente this.player = new Player()

Comment: por otro lado, si quiero aumentar el número de jugadores, tendría que modificar la clase hija, cuando mi objetivo es introducir modificaciones en el número de jugadores, sin tener que recurrir a modificar nada más que el main dándole el número de jugadores que quiero crear. 

He conseguido crear obstáculos, armas, pero como ambos se mantienen fijas no tuve problemas,

Comment: pero con los jugadores es distinto, ya que necesito moverlos y para ello tengo que acceder a los métodos de la clase player he indicar qué jugador es el que se va a mover y para ello tengo que instanciar dos jugadores o más, pero como comenté :) quiero hacer la instanciación dinámica.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes es hacer lo que dice @Trauma crear un array con los identificadores, nombres, puntos, victorias etc de los jugadores.

Para eso vas a necesitar generar un identificador único usando esta función:

```
var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
  var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
  return v.toString(16);
});
```

Con esa función se te facilitara todo, y no tendrás que agregar `player1`, `player2`, etc... Y solo tendrías que agregar los nombres de los usuarios en caso de que quieras hacerlo.

Ahora para hacerlo desde una sola clase, y crear jugares de manera dinámica a conforme se vayan uniendo al juego, seria de esta forma

```
class Game {
  constructor(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase, max_players) {
    this.map = new Map(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase);
    this.max_players = max_players;
    this._players = [];
    this._player = this.getPlayerData(); // los datos del jugador actual
  }
  uuid() {
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
      return v.toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
  }
  newPlayer(name) {
    var uuid = this.uuid();
    var players = this._players;
    var max_players = this.max_players;
    if (players.length !== max_players) {
      // con esto limitaremos un máximo se jugadores
      // y si un llegamos al limite, agregamos otro jugador
      this._players.push({
        uuid: uuid,
        name: name,
        points: 0,
        wins: 0
      });
      // guardamos los datos del jugador(uuid, name, points, wins) con 'localStorage'
      // para recordarlo y así no tender que agregarlo de nuevo
      localStorage.setItem('player', JSON.stringify({
        uuid: uuid,
        name: name,
        points: 0,
        wins: 0
      });
    }
  }
  getPlayerData() {
    var player;
    if (localStorage.getItem('player')) {
      player = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('player'));
      this._players.push(player);
    } else {
      player = {};
    }
    return player;
  }
  setPlayerData(points, wins) {
    this._player.points = points;
    this._player.wins = wins;
    // actualizamos los datos del jugador en 'localStorage'
    localStorage.setItem('player', JSON.stringify(this._player));
  }
}
```

Ya los datos del array `this._players` los usarías para mostrar una tabla de los puntos de cada jugador.

Comment: @Rimuro Tempest esta función me ha dejado loco(expresión para decir pensando) var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
      return v.toString(16);
    });

Te agradezco muchísimo tu respuesta, es mucho más de lo que busco, ya que no almaceno datos. Me la guardo, intentaré adaptarla para lo que quiero. Mi objetivo es instanciar la clase Player la cual tiene varios métodos(movimiento, detección de obstáculos, etc) Muchas gracias